# Hard Fault when using strtok()

Tags: c, strtok

I know there are a lot of other threads regarding the use of `strtok()` causing segmentation faults but it seems to be a different issue in my case. I'm using it on a STM32L4 controller and the same code works fine when compiled with an online compiler

```
void strtokTest(uint8_t* dest){
    char str[] = "1.1.2\nMore Text";
    printf("%s", str);
    char* token = strtok(str, ".");
    uint8_t index = 0;
    while(token){
        printf("%s", token);
        dest[index] = atoi(token);
        if(index++ == 2){
            break;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, ".");
    }
}
```

The first token is found correctly, but on the first call of `token = strtok(NULL, ".")` the code runs into a hard fault (probably the same as a segmentation fault would be) and I don't see why...

Update:
I'm running FreeRTOS didn't mention this before because I thought it's irrelevant but probably it isn't. It seems like if I call the `strtokTest` function before I start the scheduler it works, but if I call it from inside one of my tasks it fails.

I cannot step into with my debugger as this immediately trip the hard fault and the stack trace doesn't give much information.

[image]

Comment: This will be very hard to reproduce. At a glance I see no obvious bugs. Can you view the trace and see exactly where it crashed inside strtok?

Comment: One thing that could be a bug is if you forget to #include the relevant headers and run the compiler in C90 mode.

Comment: But shouldn't then already the first call to `strtok` fail?

Comment: No because without headers everything is passed to the function as-is. NULL may be defined as 0 which is not a pointer. After that everything fails. Fail fail fail.

Comment: This code looks fine. Is this the exact code that crashes? Or have you made changes before posting? Can you update this to a complete example where the code runs in `main` and all includes are shown. Anyway - comment out lines one by one to narrow down the problem, e.g. start by removing `dest[index] = atoi(token);` and check if you still have a crash

Comment: I have a feeling that the bug is in some code that isn't posted. For instance - how is `str` provided in the real code?

Comment: Also when using icky library stuff like stdio.h on microcontrollers, always suspect stack overflows.

Comment: @4386427 originally `str` was passed in as a pointer but during debugging I ended up with this exact code. I added the function for completeness. The only difference I have is that I'm not using `printf` directly, but the hard fault remains even when I comment out these lines.

Comment: ... ah and my `dest` array is also passed in as pointer. But again, removing the `atoi()` line doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: @po.pe I am 99.99% sure that the problem isn't related to this code. Make a complete example as I suggested above.

Comment: The simplest test I'd suggest to narrow the problem down: `char str[] = "1.1.any...thing"; char* token = strtok(str, "."); while(token) token = strtok(NULL, ".");` — will it finish or crash?

Comment: @CiaPan It crashes... as soon as step into or over `strtok(NULL, ".")`

Comment: Then I suppose something must be wrong with the `strtok` implementation. If the input string was read-only, the first call would crash, but the first call apparently succeedes, so source data are writable. The last chance it's something in your code would be the `NULL` macro definition / expansion (but I somewhat doubt it).

Comment: Again, did you include the relevant headers? What happens when you single step through strtok or read the instruction trace after hard fault? Oh and also check the map file to ensure that you didn't somehow manage to allocate the string in flash, because then everything will obviously crash.

Comment: @Lundin The 'string in flash' does not seem likely – the literal value in `char str[] = "1.1.2\nMore Text";` may reside in ROM/PROM, but it's an initializer only. The `str` variable is declared as local automatic and it remains writeable once initialized. If it was not, the first `strtok` would fail.

Comment: Added some additional information to the question

Comment: We've asked you 3 times now which headers you included. This would be the 4th time.

Comment: Sorry, just `string.h` but the headers are the same whether I'm in my `main` routine or in a thread.

Comment: What's this about threads?  Are you calling `strtok` from several different threads?  You can't do that - `strtok` has internal static data and isn't thread safe.  You'd have to use `strtok_r` instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm calling it from a thread, but only once so the static data should be consistent.

Comment: Still, it might be worth testing if switching to `strtok_r` makes the crash go away.  It's probably a good practice regardless.

Comment: @NateEldredge `strtok_r` did the trick, thanks for that! Altough I don't fully understand why it didn't work, I just used it in one thread and when I stepped through it there shouldn't have been any context switch. Do you wanna post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `strtok` is not thread-safe, in multithreaded programs it is better to use `strtok_r` if it's available (it's not provided by ISO C but it is by POSIX).  You stated in comments that this fixed your crash.

If you were truly only ever calling `strtok` from one thread (and that includes the main thread), then I don't think this should have made a difference.  So perhaps you were mistaken about which threads call this function, or maybe there is another call to `strtok` elsewhere in your program.  You may want to investigate further.

Another wild guess might be that something is wrong with the linking or loading of your program, such that `strtok`'s internal static data isn't properly allocated in writable memory.  If it ended up in ROM, one could imagine that the internal pointer would be stuck on NULL, and the second call to `strtok` would dereference it.

Or, perhaps your library's `strtok` implementation tries to use thread-local storage, to help alleviate this risk, and maybe there is something wrong with how thread-local storage is set up in your program?

Comment: Thanks, actually I even tried to suspend all other tasks during tokenizing, that also didn't help.